# VS Code insert predefined characters at the end of current line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut which-

- puts the cursor at the end of current line
- and then, insert `->`

I googled a lot. But not found any satisfactory solution.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cursor doesn't start at the end of the line you will need to use a macro extension to run two commands.  Using [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) below, make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+w",           // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "cursorEnd",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": { "text": "->" }
      }
    ]
  },
  // "when": "editorLangId == php"  // for example
}
```

[image: type an arrow at end of line]